# how to join 2 mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to join two tables to get data from both tables, for example, consider two following tables:

```
Table users:
ID      user_name       email     ...    ....


Table messages:
ID      user_name       message     ...    ...
```

The `user_name` is common column in both tables. How can I join both tables so that I can get the data from both tables. For example, I want to select the "`message`" from Table `messages` and "`email`" from table "`users`" where `user_name` is abc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT u.*, m.*
  FROM USERS u
  JOIN MESSAGES m ON m.user_name = u.user_name
 WHERE u.user_name = 'abc'
```

...to see all the users who have messages in the tables.  That means that users without messages will not appear in the output - so you might want to use the following instead:

```
   SELECT u.*, m.*
     FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN MESSAGES m ON m.user_name = u.user_name
    WHERE u.user_name = 'abc'
```

I recommend:

- reading the [Visual Explanation of JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- not using a user_name as the criteria to link data between tables, because usernames can change which would require updating all the supporting tables in this example.
- not using ANSI-89 join syntax, because it doesn't support OUTER joins and should be considered deprecated for that fact. My example is ANSI-92 syntax, and widely supported.

Comment: You forgot the OP's stated `WHERE user_name = 'abc'` requirement.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Corrected, though it's pretty trivial for someone to add themselves.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the MySQL website, there are a lot of examples on there. For the most part, people would be happier to answer if you had show some queries you'd tried and not got the results you wanted.

```
select users.user_name, users.email, messages.message from users,messages where users.user_name=messages.user_name where users.user_name='abc'
```

This is a fairly elementary SQL statement. There's a lot of clever stuff you can do. You would be wise to go see what else you can do, as rather than embed the 'abc' part you can use parameters etc.

Comment: Im dyslexic, I spend a lot of time trying to spell things correctly. My grammar as a result tends to suffer because I wasnt ever taught any. Im self taught in nearly everything I know. So, I apologise but Im sad that I get criticised for my grammer on a site about technical issues.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Please be more considerate in the future - not everyone who participates on SO/etc are native English speakers, and possibly have learning difficulties.  Providing constructive criticism would be to suggest how to re-write this better, in case you [thankfully] don't have access to do it yourself.

Comment: On reflection, it's not worth a downvote. Sorry. However it will prevent me from upvoting as it's not a well-reading answer; dyslexia doesn't prevent you from writing capital letters and full stops, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT message, email
FROM users U, messages M
WHERE U.user_name = 'abc' AND U.user_name = M.user_name;
```

Comment: Yuck - ANSI-89 join syntax :/

Comment: :) That's the syntax used in my database books. Well, now I know that it's called ANSI-89 and there is ANSI-92. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, it's valid but considered deprecated.  Kinda sad that textbooks perpetuate it when the 1992 standard superceded it :/

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.message, u.email
from 
   messages m join users u on
      m.user_name = u.user_name
where
   u.user_name = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data that matches in both tables (so not a user without a message):

```
SELECT * FROM users u, messages m WHERE u.user_name = m.user_name;
```

If you want all users regardless of messages and messages for those users who have them:

```
SELECT * FROM users u LEFT JOIN (messages m) ON (u.user_name = m.user_name);
```

EDIT: Sorry, I misread.

```
SELECT * FROM users u, messages m WHERE u.user_name = m.user_name AND u.user_name = "abc";
```