# Mysql: 2 table Join

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: student_courses (id/student_id/course_id) and student_questionnaires (id/student_id/course_id/details). Basically, I want to run through the student_courses table and return a list of anyone who IS signed up for a course (in the student_courses table), but HAVE NOT filled out a questionnaire (no entry in student_questionnaires). I've tried the following:

```
SELECT sc.* FROM student_courses as sc
LEFT JOIN student_questionnaires as sq on sq.course_id=sc.course_id AND sq.student_id=sc.student_id
```

I've played around with the type of join, but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to join 2 mysql tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524804/how-to-join-2-mysql-tables)

Comment: @AdrianCornish I don't think it's a dupe.  That poster (from the question you linked) is asking for a straight-up JOIN of two tables. This OP is asking for rows in one table that are not in another.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 then it is a duplicate of another - all possible 2 join mysql table questions have been asked here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `sq.course_id IS NULL`:

```
SELECT sc.*
FROM
  student_courses sc
  LEFT JOIN student_questionnaires sq ON sc.student_id = sq.student_id AND sc.course_id = sq.course_id
WHERE sq.course_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT sc.* 
FROM student_courses as sc
WHERE sc.student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM student_questionnaires)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Student_ID
FROM Student_Courses
WHERE LENGTH(COALESCE(Course_ID)) <> 0 AND Student_ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT student_id Student_Questionnaires)
```